# Append javascript variable into erb tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Unable to add the image name dynamically in asset_path

my.js.erb file

```
var path = element.image_path
var imgObj = new Image();
imgObj.src = "<%= asset_path("+ path +") %>"; // text var comes in loop(image1.png, image2.png)
```

EDIT:

I am asking how to do this with dynamic image path
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#javascript-coffeescript-and-erb

Comment: How about this `imgObj.src = "<%= asset_path(path) %>";`

Comment: Nope, you can't do that. `asset_path` (as well as all other "ERB tags") runs on the server, __long before__ this javascript code will have a chance to run. But if you find a way to have this image_path on server too...

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can render the `asset_path` for your image in a controller with the following method:

```
ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag("YOUR_IMAGE")
```

Give it to an instance variable, then apply it however you wish in the view.

Comment: In my case, it has to be dynamically added in javascript

Comment: Store it as a data attribute on your `element` and then access it via javascript

Comment: @Sam: "it has to be dynamically added in javascript" - if you have a finite (and small enough) number of the images, you can precalculate asset paths for ALL of them at page render time, then simply select one of them. If you have large/unlimited set of images, you can either avoid fingerprinting them (thus avoiding the need for `asset_path`) or send an ajax request to get the path (because `asset_path` only runs on the server)